# Unit Testing Error :Cannot read property 'map' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing

I am trying to do a unit test for the following code but I am not sure how to mock this.props that contains map on it

ERROR:  Cannot read property 'map' of undefined

Is this  prop correct ? this.props.fromStatusList. I have the other props right

Here is part of the BatchAccount.js code :

```
 renderFromDropdown = () => {
let fromList = this.props.fromStatusList;
let result = fromList.map((item) => {
```

Here is how I am mocking the props in BatchAccount.test.js

```
describe( 'BatchUpdateAccountModal test: ', () => {

let tree;
let baseProps;
let mockfromStatusList;
```

And then I list them under beforeEach (() =>

```
 beforeEach(() => {

    baseProps = {
fromStatusList : mockfromStatusList,
```

and run a test to check if it renders with  all of the props for example :

```
  it(' Should render with all of the props ', () => {  
tree = renderer.create(<BatchUpdateAccountModal {...baseProps} />)
let treeJson = tree.toJSON()
expect(treeJson).toMatchSnapshot();
tree.unmount()
```

});

Comment: in your case `pathname` is an object. You can't split an object. Try setting pathname to equal "test" instead.

Comment: @Charlie for some odd reason - the previous file worked. This is the error that is showing up when I create a test file in the same folder .